# Splitting lines (orders) EBS Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-ebs

I've been trying without success to obtain **all** the different lines that were created from the original line and the **DATE**

I mean, an order line can be manually splitted into two or more lines. So, i wanna know which lines were created from the original line.

I know that there exist the command **split_from_line** but i dont know how to use it :/

These are my queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM oe_order_headers_all
WHERE order_number = 
--and org_id =
```

and

```
SELECT
HEADER_ID
,LINE_ID
,LINE_TYPE_ID
,FLOW_STATUS_CODE
,LINE_NUMBER
,ORDERED_ITEM
,ORDERED_QUANTITY
,UNIT_LIST_PRICE_PER_PQTY
FROM OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL
WHERE 1=1
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the lines table you need to append other fields to line number to get split lines.  The fields that need to be appended depend on what has caused the lines to split.

For example if the line split due to backorder and shipped on different deliveries, then the line has multiple shipments.

In that case:

```
    select line_number||'.'||shipment_number from oe_order_lines_all;
```

Giving you lines 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ..

There are other reason that the line can split, such as components from customizer.

Do you know what is causing your lines to split?